# pickle.load() EOFerror with filled txt file

Tags: python, pickle, eoferror

I have a small piece of code in my program that imports a dict from a text file
It gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\S.Latil\Desktop\Python\HomeWork Full\HomeWork\test.py", line 3, in <module>
    Lesson = pickle.load(Li)
EOFError
```

My code is:

```
import pickle

with open('LessonOut.txt', 'rb') as Li:
 Lesson = pickle.load(Li)

print(Lesson)
```

In the file LessonOut.txt i have this string:

```
€}q X   helloqX   worldqs.
```

I don't understand why it gives me this error, I haven't seen a fix in other threads.
What it should print is {'hello','world'}
If anyone could explain why this error occurs and how to fix it it would be great

Comment: I don't suppose you could provide the code that wrote that string into LessonOut.txt? I tried just copy-pasting it but it told me "unsupported pickle protocol", so I think something is being lost in translation.

Comment: Strange, now it works even though i changed nothing... Well thanks for your time, i'll delete this thread in a few minutes

Comment: Are you sure content in 'LessonOut.txt' is the generated by pickle.dump(obj, file, protocol=None)? Try use different protocols to dump, and see the result file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error to the problem actually, it's pretty simple.
What happened was that i copyed and pasted the content of a pickle output file into my txt and because pickle doesn't use only ascii characters it didn't copy properly. All i did was redump the dict onto the file and it worked.
Hope this helped someone.